# Why does the list functor represent a context of nondeterministic choice?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

What does this quote mean?

```
the list functor represents a context of nondeterministic choice;
```

In the context of Functors in functional programming.

I think I understand that a Functor is a "container" of some kind along with the ability to apply a function uniformly to elements in the container without altering the structure. So maybe is a Functor that represents a context or container with possible failure, but why does list represent a context or container with nondeterministic choice?

Comment: Where is this quote from?  I've heard of the list _monad_ representing the nondeterministic choice, but not the list _functor_.

Comment: The quote is from: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Instances

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As best as I can tell, a calculation is "nondeterministic" if it has multiple possible answers. Well, a list can contain multiple possible answers. So that's why.

(As to why it's called nondeterministic, I have no idea... I would have expected nondeterministic to mean *random*, which is something quite different.)

Comment: Nondeterminism is not pure randomness, it is making an arbitrary choice between specific options. One way to model nondeterminism is to make *all* of the possible choices (and lists can be used for this model), though typically, when we talk about a nondeterministic machine, it only makes one choice, and we are unable to predict which choice it will make, though we know exactly what choices it *could* make.

Comment: Yes: in the sense of the quote, lists are used as a low-rent multiset, and represent "nondeterministic choice" by keeping every possible outcome.

Comment: If it helps at all, this is the same "nondeterministic" as in an NFA (nondeterministic finite-state automata) or an NTM (nondeterministic Turing machine).

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of NTM, which is apparently where the term comes from. I just don't get why it's called "nondeterministic" when it _does_ clearly follow set rules.

Comment: I suspect the TM definition of nondeterminism actually predates the "random" interpretation.

Comment: A computation on an NTM can also be thought of as having an oracle that "guesses" each time you need to make a choice. So from the perspective of the computation being run on the NTM, it's just a normal program with parts that are decided by an outside force (e.g. nondeterministically). Coincidentally, this is how NP is defined--if you have a program that would run in polynomial time given an oracle like this, it's in NP. So they're programs that, from the perspective of an NTM run in polynomial time, but in reality take exponential time (simulating an NTM on a TM takes exponential time).

Comment: Rabin & Scott introduced the term in 'Finite Automata and Their Decision Problems'(1959). "At each stage of its motion across a tape it will be at liberty to choose one of several new internal states. Of course, some sequence of choices will lead either to impossible situations from which no moves are possible or to final states not in the designated class F. We disre-gard all such failures, however, and agree to let the ma-chine accept a tape if there is at least one winning com-bination of choices of states leading to a designated final state." They're both still alive, so we could ask them.

Comment: Haskell lists induce particular order; true non-determinism would be correctly modeled by unordered lists with unpredictable order. "Oracles" produce "best" choices first.

Answer (score 8):

Traditionally, in computability and complexity, a nondeterministic computation model has referred to a model in which case you can "branch".  Wikipedia explains it like so:

> In computational complexity theory, nondeterministic algorithms are ones that, at every possible step, can allow for multiple continuations (imagine a man walking down a path in a forest and, every time he steps further, he must pick which fork in the road he wishes to take). These algorithms do not arrive at a solution for every possible computational path; however, they are guaranteed to arrive at a correct solution for some path (i.e., the man walking through the forest may only find his cabin if he picks some combination of "correct" paths). The choices can be interpreted as guesses in a search process.

In the list monad, this is exactly what you're doing.  For example, consider this solution to the decision version of the [clique problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem), in the list monad:

```
cliques :: Int -> Graph -> [[Node]]
cliques 0 _ = [[]]
cliques minCliqueSize graph = do
  v <- nodes graph
  vs <- cliques (minCliqueSize - 1) (deleteNode v graph)
  mapM_ (\ w -> guard (isAdjacent v w graph)) vs
  return (v:vs)
```

This is exactly how you'd program e.g. a nondeterministic Turing machine to solve the clique problem.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following:

```
foo = do
  x <- [1 .. 10]
  y <- [2, 3, 5, 7]
  return (x * y)
```

What is `foo`? Well, it is `x * y`, except with the nondeterministic choices of `x` being a number from 1 to 10, and y being either 2, 3, 5, or 7. Therefore, foo is `[2, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 10, 14, etc... ]`

Answer (score 5):

In addition to viewing a functor as a container, you can also view it as a certain kind of context. Your values are in that context, and if you want to operate on them, you use `map` to lift a function into the context. Another way of putting it is that your values are augmented with that context.

To understand how the list functor is a context of nondeterministic choice, it may be useful to see how another functor is a context: The Maybe functor is a context of a computation that may fail. If you try to apply a function to a value in a Maybe functor, the resulting value will still keep the same context of whether or not it was a failed computation in the first place.

In the same way, a list can be seen as the result of a computation that does not have a deterministic result, but whose result might instead be chosen nondeterministically from one of several values. If you tried to map a function over a list with 3 elements, those elements would be changed, but the context of being able to choose between three values would remain the same.

Borrowing a bit from Dan Burtons answer, look at the monadic notation for lists:

```
foo = do
  x <- [1 .. 10]
  y <- [2, 3, 5, 7]
  return (x * y)
```

It seems at first a bit odd, since the notation seems to indicate, that you could extract a single value from each of the lists, but then you get as result a list that is 40 elements long. It makes more sense when you look at functors (well, monads in this case) as a context for a single value. In the example, `x` and `y` are such values, but their context is that they are nondeterministic. When you multiply two such values, you get even more nondeterminism, resulting in a longer list. So with monads and `>>=`, the context can be changed, whereas with functors and `map`, it cannot.

Comment: _"So with monads and >>=, the context can be changed"_ Can you elaborate that? `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` indicates that the context `m` must be preserved. Or do you mean by context the shape of `a`, which is a List `[a]` in your example?

Comment: Yeah, it's the shape of the context. If you map over a list, it keeps the same number of items, and if you map over a Maybe, it stays either a Just or a Nothing. But if you use, `>>=` then you can change the number of elements in the list, and you can change a Just to a nothing. And similarly for other monads. But it is just one way of looking at monads, there are other monads where it doesn't really make sense to look at it as a data value with a given structure, IO for instance.

Comment: `<*>`/`>>=` can't always preserve the shape of the context because they combine two contexts. And `pure`/`return` come to the rescue by providing a minimal context that combined with another context guaranteed not alter the shape of that context. `pure`/`return` are needed because of the applicative/monad laws. I've eventually understood it :D

Answer (score 4):

"Classical" computations take 1 input and give 1 output.
What you want to represent with these non-deterministic computations is: What can I say about the output if I am not sure about the input?

Two usual ways to represent the uncertainty is to consider:

1. that the input is an element of a given set
2. that the input is given by a known probability distribution

As an example, consider the function (2*) that doubles it input.
What can you say about the output of that function when the input is the result of a die roll?

1. I know the die has 6 faces so the result is in the set {2,4,6,8,10,12}
2. I know the probabilities of each face is 1/6 so I know that each of these numbers has probability 1/6 to appear

The list functor represents non-deterministic computations in the sense of 1.: it represents sets by lists.